# What is the point of TFS Gated check-in committed message - reconcile your workspace with the repository?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

What is the point of the following message after gated check-in? It doesn't make sense to me. "If you did not undo your local pending changes when you submitted your check-in, you may need to reconcile your workspace with the repository."

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's say you are performing a Gated Check-in of a Single file - **Progam.cs**.

When you perform a Gated Check-in and choose **not** to undo your local changes, you Shelve **Program.cs** to the server and perform a build with the Latest code + that Shelveset. If the build succeeds, then TFS automatically Checks in the **shelveset** (containing your changes to **Program.cs**) into the source control.

Now, because you didn't undo the changes on your local workspace, you will still have **Progam.cs** as a "Pending Change" with the status of "edit". This "edit" is not needed as TFS has already checked in your change. Clicking "Reconcile..." will undo that local change and bring it in line with what is on the server.

Comment: Confused. So choosing 'Reconcile...' will undo my local changes that I actually want to check-in?

Comment: Yes, it will undo them, **BUT** that is because TFS has already checked in the "Shelveset" it created for you, so you won't loose any work. I'll try and clarify my answer.

Comment: So is Reconcile an indirect way to mark files as unmodified once they have been successfully checked in? If so, why would I ever not want to do Reconcile and why doesn't VS TFS do this automatically when my changes are checked in?

Comment: You didn't "Check-in" the changes, you "Shelved" them, and performed a build with that Shelveset. TFS checked in that Shelveset, but left your Workspace untouched - if the build failed, it would **not** have checked them in, so could make more changes to fix the build. You may be about to modify Program.cs again, so you might just want to ignore, and carry on.

Comment: So, if I do a gated check in, then start editing Program.cs, after check-in is successful, it will offer me to Reconcile Program.cs? I can potentially undo changes that I made after I initiated the check-in?

Comment: I don't know what will happen in this case. I don't have anything setup to test with. It may "reverse merge" your change, or may just perform an "Undo". I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I've seen new pending changes "undone" with a Reconcile.  I hate how TFS implements this.  It knows perfectly well what changes you tried to commit and it should just handle it quietly unless there's a conflict.

Comment: I agree @Jeff. This is very painful in both cases i.e. when changes are successfully checked in and also when build fails. Because if build fails, I will have to put aside the new pending changes which I made after I did gated check-in into new shelveset which will contain breaking changes (can't help it) and then undo the shelveset from the failed build. Only straight option available is go for a coffee after every check in. :D

Comment: The correct answer was already given by DaveShaw but I wanted to add that there is a suggestion that was posted in visualstudio.uservoice.com for Microsoft to implement Auto-Reconcile in Visual Studio. If you would like to vote to support this suggestion, here's the link: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2980684-automatic-reconcile-to-workspace.

Comment: Just came across this after creating a gated build in TFS 2013 for the first time. Totally perplexed: while I understand this explanation, I don't understand the purpose of the feature. If all the checks pass, why would you ever *not* want to reconcile?

Comment: Maybe you had reconciled them already. Or were making other changes to those files.

Comment: "Clicking 'Reconcile...' will undo that local change and bring it in line with what is on the server." But the local changes *are* in line with what's on the server, so it sounds to me like no action is taken (which sounds like *ignoring*). And what happens if you click "Ignore"? I'm still confused. What am I missing?

Comment: @cp.engr If you click ignore, your local workspace will be marked at the checkin that you last performed a GET for. If you click reconcile, your workspace will update the local workspace state to the reconciled checkin. This is the same process that happens when other workers checkin. Your workspace stays at a previous state. You may want to do this if the other party checked in something bad. As for reconcile, if the checkin build took a long time, you may have continued working. Hitting reconcile would then force you to manually or automatically merge changes.